# How to draw in Windows Phone(substitute to graphics in Java)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there any substitute to the Java's graphics in the Windows Phone. I would like to draw a component(watch hand like) which indicates how much the user is away from the "correct state". It is for the guitar tuner.
Thanks

PS: I don't want to use it XAML at all to do it, just simple paint graphics and repaint when needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to open your project in Expression Blend. 
It lets you draw various components, add pictures, edit pictures and add Story lines to it.

For Instance, Once you draw the hand, based on the tuner, you could adjust the Width of the Hand to let the user know how far he is away from the required target. 
Expression Blend also lets you make storyboards if you wish to include animations.